# Hotkeys and .load() issue

Tags: jquery

I have a webpage that uses hotkeys.

```
function HOTKEYS(){
  var keys = {};
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    keys[e.which] = 1;
    if (keys[80] == 1 && keys[18] == 1) {
      $('input[name=customer]').focus();
    }

    if (keys[65] == 1 && keys[18] == 1) {
      $('input[name=product]').focus();
    }

    if (keys[86] == 1 && keys[18] == 1) {
      add_conn();
    }

    if (keys[83] == 1 && keys[18] == 1) {
      edit_price();
    }

    console.log(keys);
  });

  $(document).keyup(function(e){
    delete keys[e.which];
  });
}
```

The hotkeys work fine, until one of the hotkeys opens up an event that activates a `load()` function. After that the function `HOTKEYS()` stops working.

Is there a way to fix that without including the function HOTKEYS() again after the .load() event ?

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
    var keys = {};
    $(document).on('keydown',function(e) {
        keys[e.which] = 1;
        if (keys[80] == 1 && keys[18] == 1) {
            $('input[name=customer]').focus();
        }

        if (keys[65] == 1 && keys[18] == 1) {
            $('input[name=product]').focus();
        }

        if (keys[86] == 1 && keys[18] == 1) {
            add_conn();
        }

        if (keys[83] == 1 && keys[18] == 1) {
            edit_price();
        }

        console.log(keys);
    });

    $(document).keyup(function(e){
        delete keys[e.which];
    });
}());
```

Do it this way.

Comment: Still not working. The same thing happens, it works until i press Alt+A, which activates

`$('.popup').load(url,function(){ some code })`

After that the hotkeys stop working.